# How to make fontforge a python extension

Tags: python, svg, image-processing, fontforge, potrace

I've installed [font-forge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/downloads/windows-dl/) for windows 10. I am currently using python 3.7 and I want to convert image to font. So what I am trying to do is to convert image to .svg using Potrace then converting .svg to font by font-forge. (Better suggestions to convert image to font are also welcomed.) 
I know that I can open fontforge-console.bat file and write ffpython <filename.py> to do this. 
But I want to make font forge a pyhton extension so that I can just do it by importing it like "import fontforge" in the python file. 
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library for python2:

```
import fontforge # only works with python2
```

I have recently developed a script for batch processing svg files to TrueType fonts using FontForge. I have tested it only on linux, but you can try it on Windows. fontforge executable must be in PATH and it requires Pythos 3.6+

https://github.com/mnesarco/ff-batch